# Create a new activity for each Name - dynamic crm

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2015

Im trying to create a new activity from each individual value.
What I have done so far is shown below in snippets to get each value.

```
var Names = recordRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Split(",".ToArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);'
```

For each value in  in the cell, populate a field in  the activity form

```
 foreach (var Name in Names)
                    {
                        newAct.RegardingObjectId = new EntityReference(Lead.EntityLogicalName, actualCRMLead.Id);
                        _xrm.Create(newAct);
                    }
```

How do it create a new activity once the RegardObjectId field in populated?

Thanks,

EDIT 1;
If there are 3 names  in the one cell it will create 9 activities, how can I stop it from creating duplicates?

Comment: _xrm.Create(newAct) should be sufficient to create a new activity.  Without a more holistic code set, there's no way to say how to prevent duplicates.  What exactly is your rule for determining what is a duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming _xrm is the variable that stores the Organization Service Object (and that was properly instantiated), then you have the correct snippet to create a newAct object and to set the regarding field to the "actualCRMLead"